# Comparison of 2 treatment groups using proportions

Tags: proportion, treatment-effect

I have two treatment groups  (lets say A and B)  with pre/post data for two diffirent populations and there are statistically significant differences (p<0.05) between before and after treatments, for both. For instance, the mean before treatment A is 10, the mean after treatment A is 5, for the first group. And, the mean before treatment B is 20, the mean after treatment B is 3, for the second group.
Reduction rate is bigger in second group and this is meaningfull from a specialist perspective. How can I say statistically if the second treatment is better? Which test should I use?

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic case for *mixed ANOVA*, which allows you to specify within subjects factors (pre vs. post) and between subjects factors (A  vs. B). You want to know if the effect of pre vs. post differs between A and B. This corresponds to testing the interaction between pre vs. post and A vs. B. In a software that performs mixed ANOVA, this will be part of the output.

Mixed ANOVA can be a little complicated, and in your case it turns out the analysis is equivalent to an independent samples t-test on the post-pre difference scores between A and B. If the difference in the difference scores is significant, then the effect of pre vs. post differs across A vs. B. The p-value you get from this test will be identical to that from the mixed ANOVA.

All this assumes you have individual-level data and that the outcome is continuous. You mention having proportion data in the title but not in the question, so I'm not sure how that is relevant here. With binary outcomes, you'll have to resort to using a model that can account for them, like multilevel logistic regression.